# GoogleMaps.oncameraChangedListener is never called

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I have an Activity (which inflates a map fragment) which implements the GoogleMap.onCameraChangedListener, and I have overriden the onCameraChange method.

The problem is that whenever I move across the map, i.e. the camera position changes, the onCameraChange method is never called.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Please post your Activity class code!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this :

```
 public class MapActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener{
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.googlemap_layout);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();

     }

@Override
public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
    double latitude = cameraPosition.target.latitude;
    double longitude = cameraPosition.target.longitude;

}
private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {

    if (googleMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        if (googleMap != null) {

            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(false);
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
            googleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(this);

        }
    }
}
```

}

Layout :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I was so dumb that I forgot to call the setOnCameraChangeListener() method!!