# Android onCameraChange in Fragment is never called

Tags: android, google-maps, fragment, listener

I'm trying to set a listener to catch camera moves but it doesn't work. The method onCameraChange, implemented by the Fragment that host the SupportMapFragment, is never called also if I set up all right. [This similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31633404/googlemaps-oncamerachangedlistener-is-never-called) didn't help me.

Here's the code of the Fragment:

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener {
private static final String TAG = MapFragment.class.getSimpleName();
private static final int MY_LOCATION_REQUEST_PERMISSION = 100;
private static final int ENABLE_LOCATION_REQUEST_PERMISSION = 200;

private int mShortAnimationDuration;
private ImageButton checkin;
private LinearLayout big_checkin;

private GoogleMap mMap;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private double mLatitude, mLongitude;

private SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment;

public MapFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
    }
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    buildGoogleApiClient();


}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView");
    }
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);

    final SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    final DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.map_toolbar);
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            getActivity(), drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    autocompleteFragment = (SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment)
            getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);

    return view;
}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getContext())
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
}


private void getMyLocation() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(),
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        PermissionUtils.requestPermission((AppCompatActivity) getActivity(), MY_LOCATION_REQUEST_PERMISSION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, false);
    } else {
        final Location lastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                mGoogleApiClient);
        if (lastLocation != null) {
            mLatitude = lastLocation.getLatitude();
            mLongitude = lastLocation.getLongitude();
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(mLatitude, mLongitude);
            CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 17);
            if (mMap != null) {
                mMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
                mClusterManager.clearItems();
                addItems();
            }
        } else {
            if (mMap != null) {
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(false);
            }
            final ImageButton myLocation = (ImageButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.my_location); //TODO migliorare
            myLocation.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroyView");
    }
    super.onDestroyView();

    mMap = null;
    mGoogleApiClient = null;
    autocompleteFragment = null;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
    }
    super.onStart();
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null)
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStop");
    }
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == MY_LOCATION_REQUEST_PERMISSION) {
        if (PermissionUtils.isPermissionGranted(permissions, grantResults,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
            // Enable the my location layer if the permission has been granted.

            getMyLocation();
        } else {
            //TODO avvisare che si devono dare i permessi?
            // Display the missing permission error dialog when the fragments resume.
        }
    } else if (requestCode == ENABLE_LOCATION_REQUEST_PERMISSION) {
        if (PermissionUtils.isPermissionGranted(permissions, grantResults,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
            // Enable the my location layer if the permission has been granted.
            enableMyLocation();
        } else {
            //TODO avvisare che si devono dare i permessi?
            // Display the missing permission error dialog when the fragments resume.
        }
    }

}

private void enableMyLocation() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(),
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        PermissionUtils.requestPermission((AppCompatActivity) getActivity(), ENABLE_LOCATION_REQUEST_PERMISSION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, false);
    } else {
        if (mMap != null) {
            // Access to the location has been granted to the app.
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            //getMyLocation();
        }
    }
}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        Log.d(TAG, "mapReady");
    }
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(this);
    enableMyLocation();
    setUpClusterer();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnected");
    }
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(),
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        PermissionUtils.requestPermission((AppCompatActivity) getActivity(), MY_LOCATION_REQUEST_PERMISSION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, false);
    } else {
        final Location lastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                mGoogleApiClient);
        if (lastLocation != null) {
            mLatitude = lastLocation.getLatitude();
            mLongitude = lastLocation.getLongitude();
            CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(mLatitude, mLongitude), 17);
            if (mMap != null) {
                mMap.moveCamera(cameraUpdate);
                mClusterManager.clearItems();
                addItems();
            }
        } else {
            if (mMap != null) {
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(false);
            }
            final ImageButton myLocation = (ImageButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.my_location); //TODO migliorare
            myLocation.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    Log.i("GOOGLE API CLIENT", "Connection suspended");
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

@Override
public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCameraChange");
    }
    LatLng center = cameraPosition.target;
    Snackbar.make(getView(), center.latitude + " - " + center.longitude, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
}

}
```

Here's the layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="me.grinworld.grinpark.MapFragment">

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/map_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/map_bar"
    android:elevation="3dp"
    android:padding="3dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/map_bar_search">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/fav_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite_idle"/>
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/fav_icon"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Maybe because of you didn't `show()` the snackbar. `SnackBar.make().show();`

Comment: @Aryan no, it doesn't matter what there is inside the method, I debugged it and checked that the method is never called. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**RESOLVED.**
I just noticed that, since I was using ClusterManager, I set up as onCameraChangeListener this manager, that obviously overrode my custom method.